# Using sping's restTemplate with a timeout, how do I detect a timeout?

Tags: java, spring-boot, timeout, resttemplate, connection-timeout

I've initialized my restTemplate as follows:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(1000);
requestFactory.setReadTimeout(1000);
restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

and I'm calling it like so:

```
restTemplate.getForEntity(someString, String.class, SomeHashmapWithURLParameters)
```

How do I handle both timeouts? I assume an exception will be thrown? If so which specific exception can I catch, in order to specifically handle just timeouts. I'm handeling other exceptions in different ways.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In case of `RestTemplate`, when the request gets timed out, Spring will throw [ResourceAccessException](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/ResourceAccessException.html). Underlying exception under that instance will be `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` with message 'Read timed out'.

Comment: ResourceAccessException is being thrown in case of Socket timeout or connection Timeout, so you need to check if ex.getCause is of type socket timeout exception.
I have solved it by the following if statement:

 

 if (ex instanceof InterruptedException || (ex instanceof ResourceAccessException && ex.getCause() instanceof   SocketTimeoutException)) {

Comment: @amirbayan is there any official spring documentation that explicitly note that RestTemplate throws a RAE with the underlying STE? the javadoc in the answer does not, unfortunately, and I need some official doc

Comment: @amirbayan why do you treat InterruptedException  as timeout exception?

Comment: since in case of timeout, the thread will be interrupted and it will throw that exception. from the description of Interrupted Exception: Thrown when a thread is waiting, sleeping, or otherwise occupied, and the thread is interrupted, either before or during the activity.